# GWT load testing with jmeter+ubik load plugin shows error converting XML to GWTRPC

Tags: gwt, jmeter, ubikloadpack

I am trying to run load tests on my GWT application with jmeter + ubik load plugin. I am able to convert the GWT RPC to XML. But when I try to do the other way round, my application server throws following error:

> com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException:
>   This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on
>   your browser. ( Malformed or old RPC message received - expecting
>   version between 5 and 7 )

The jmeter logs show the following error:

> **ERROR** c.u.j.p.g.p.GwtPreProcessor: Error converting XML to GWTRPC
>   format, message:class
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Is there anyone who has used this plugin before and can help me with this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably didn't add as child of Test Plan

- ULP GWT PreProcessor

Add it and try again.

You can contact our support for more details.

Comment: Does it need to be child of the Test Plan or child of Thread? I have in fact added it as a child of the Thread Group.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Can you contact support, they 'll give you more details on what to provide.